# Bouncycastle PGP decrypt and verify

Tags: java, encryption, bouncycastle, sign, pgp

I'm trying to decrypt and verify a PGP message using the java BouncyCastle libraries, but am running into issues, complaining about premature ends of PartialInputStream.

I know the encrypt works fine, because I can decrypt and verify messages created with the encrypt function using gpg on the command line.

Here's the code:

```
public static void signEncryptMessage(InputStream in, OutputStream out, PGPPublicKey publicKey, PGPPrivateKey secretKey, SecureRandom rand) throws Exception {
        out = new ArmoredOutputStream(out);

        PGPEncryptedDataGenerator encryptedDataGenerator = new PGPEncryptedDataGenerator(new BcPGPDataEncryptorBuilder(PGPEncryptedData.AES_256).setWithIntegrityPacket(true).setSecureRandom(rand));
        encryptedDataGenerator.addMethod(new BcPublicKeyKeyEncryptionMethodGenerator(publicKey));

        OutputStream compressedOut = new PGPCompressedDataGenerator(PGPCompressedData.ZIP).open(encryptedDataGenerator.open(out, 4096), new byte[4096]);

        PGPSignatureGenerator signatureGenerator = new PGPSignatureGenerator(new BcPGPContentSignerBuilder(publicKey.getAlgorithm(), HashAlgorithmTags.SHA512));
        signatureGenerator.init(PGPSignature.BINARY_DOCUMENT, secretKey);
        signatureGenerator.generateOnePassVersion(true).encode(compressedOut);

        OutputStream finalOut = new PGPLiteralDataGenerator().open(compressedOut, PGPLiteralData.BINARY, "", new Date(), new byte[4096]);

        byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
            finalOut.write(buf, 0, len);
            signatureGenerator.update(buf, 0, len);
        }

        finalOut.close();
        in.close();
        signatureGenerator.generate().encode(compressedOut);
        compressedOut.close();
        encryptedDataGenerator.close();
        out.close();
    }

    public static void decryptVerifyMessage(InputStream in, OutputStream out, PGPPrivateKey secretKey, PGPPublicKey publicKey) throws Exception {
        in = new ArmoredInputStream(in);

        PGPObjectFactory pgpF = new PGPObjectFactory(in);
        PGPEncryptedDataList enc = (PGPEncryptedDataList) pgpF.nextObject();

        PGPObjectFactory plainFact = new PGPObjectFactory(((PGPPublicKeyEncryptedData) enc.getEncryptedDataObjects().next()).getDataStream(new JcePublicKeyDataDecryptorFactoryBuilder().setProvider("BC").build(secretKey)));

        Object message = null;

        PGPOnePassSignatureList onePassSignatureList = null;
        PGPSignatureList signatureList = null;
        PGPCompressedData compressedData = null;

        message = plainFact.nextObject();
        ByteArrayOutputStream actualOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        while (message != null) {
            System.out.println(message.toString());
            if (message instanceof PGPCompressedData) {
                compressedData = (PGPCompressedData) message;
                plainFact = new PGPObjectFactory(compressedData.getDataStream());
                message = plainFact.nextObject();
                System.out.println(message.toString());
            }

            if (message instanceof PGPLiteralData) {
                Streams.pipeAll(((PGPLiteralData) message).getInputStream(), actualOutput);
            } else if (message instanceof PGPOnePassSignatureList) {
                onePassSignatureList = (PGPOnePassSignatureList) message;
            } else if (message instanceof PGPSignatureList) {
                signatureList = (PGPSignatureList) message;
            } else {
                throw new PGPException("message unknown message type.");
            }
            message = plainFact.nextObject();
        }
        actualOutput.close();
        byte[] output = actualOutput.toByteArray();
        if (onePassSignatureList == null || signatureList == null) {
            throw new PGPException("Poor PGP. Signatures not found.");
        } else {

            for (int i = 0; i < onePassSignatureList.size(); i++) {
                PGPOnePassSignature ops = onePassSignatureList.get(0);
                System.out.println("verifier : " + ops.getKeyID());
                if (publicKey != null) {
                    ops.init(new JcaPGPContentVerifierBuilderProvider().setProvider("BC"), publicKey);
                    ops.update(output);
                    PGPSignature signature = signatureList.get(i);
                    if (ops.verify(signature)) {
                        Iterator<?> userIds = publicKey.getUserIDs();
                        while (userIds.hasNext()) {
                            String userId = (String) userIds.next();
                            System.out.println("Signed by " + userId);
                        }
                        System.out.println("Signature verified");
                    } else {
                        throw new SignatureException("Signature verification failed");
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        out.write(output);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Security.insertProviderAt(new BouncyCastleProvider(), 0);
        byte inBytes[] = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.".getBytes();

        try {
            SecureRandom rand = new SecureRandom();

            RSAKeyPairGenerator kpg = new RSAKeyPairGenerator();
            kpg.init(new RSAKeyGenerationParameters(BigInteger.valueOf(0x10001), rand, 1024, 90));

            BcPGPKeyPair sender = new BcPGPKeyPair(PGPPublicKey.RSA_GENERAL, kpg.generateKeyPair(), new Date());
            BcPGPKeyPair recip = new BcPGPKeyPair(PGPPublicKey.RSA_GENERAL, kpg.generateKeyPair(), new Date());

            ByteArrayOutputStream sendMessage = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ByteArrayOutputStream recvMessage = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            signEncryptMessage(new ByteArrayInputStream(inBytes), sendMessage, recip.getPublicKey(), sender.getPrivateKey(), rand);

            System.out.println(sendMessage.toString());

            decryptVerifyMessage(new ByteArrayInputStream(sendMessage.toByteArray()), recvMessage, recip.getPrivateKey(), sender.getPublicKey());

            System.out.println(recvMessage.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

After a few runs of `message = plainFact.nextObject();` the exception is thrown:

```
-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----
Version: BCPG v1.49
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=ApMf
-----END PGP MESSAGE-----

org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPCompressedData@cd36a6d
org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPOnePassSignatureList@7e224235
org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPLiteralData@7b28e644
java.io.EOFException: premature end of stream in PartialInputStream
    at org.bouncycastle.bcpg.BCPGInputStream$PartialInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.bcpg.BCPGInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
    at javax.crypto.CipherInputStream.getMoreData(CipherInputStream.java:103)
    at javax.crypto.CipherInputStream.read(CipherInputStream.java:177)
    at org.bouncycastle.bcpg.BCPGInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPEncryptedData$TruncatedStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:170)
    at org.bouncycastle.util.io.TeeInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.bcpg.BCPGInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.bcpg.BCPGInputStream$PartialInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.bcpg.BCPGInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPCompressedData$1.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
    at org.bouncycastle.bcpg.BCPGInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.bcpg.BCPGInputStream$PartialInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.bcpg.BCPGInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.util.io.Streams.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.bcpg.BCPGInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.bcpg.BCPGInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.bcpg.MPInteger.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.bcpg.SignaturePacket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.bcpg.BCPGInputStream.readPacket(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPSignature.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPObjectFactory.nextObject(Unknown Source)
    at main.decryptVerifyMessage(main.java:113)
    at main.main(main.java:167)
```

Any ideas?

Side note, this decryption code came from [How to decrypt a signed pgp encrypted file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827725/how-to-decrypt-a-signed-pgp-encrypted-file), slightly modified to suit: Messages will only be coming from that encryption method, and handling of the keys directly instead of key streams.

Cheers

Ramo

Comment: did you found any solution?

Answer (score 13):

I was recently trying to do the same kind of thing and put together this method based on code I found in the Bouncycastle examples and on tutorials I found on the web. For my purposes, my code has a singleton crypto object that has a public/private key pair. In the example code, you could replace

```
    INSTANCE._secretKeyRingCollection.getSecretKey(pbe.getKeyID());
```

with your secret key. I've tested this method with a long-lived process that did several tens of encrypt & sign / decrypt & verify actions and didn't get the exception you're seeing.

```
public static void decryptAndVerify(InputStream in, OutputStream fOut, InputStream publicKeyIn) throws IOException, SignatureException, PGPException {
    in = PGPUtil.getDecoderStream(in);

    PGPObjectFactory pgpF = new PGPObjectFactory(in);
    PGPEncryptedDataList enc;

    Object o = pgpF.nextObject();
    //
    // the first object might be a PGP marker packet.
    //
    if (o instanceof PGPEncryptedDataList) {
        enc = (PGPEncryptedDataList) o;
    } else {
        enc = (PGPEncryptedDataList) pgpF.nextObject();
    }

    //
    // find the secret key
    //
    Iterator<PGPPublicKeyEncryptedData> it = enc.getEncryptedDataObjects();
    PGPPrivateKey sKey = null;
    PGPPublicKeyEncryptedData pbe = null;
    while (sKey == null && it.hasNext()) {
        pbe = it.next();
        PBESecretKeyDecryptor decryptor = new BcPBESecretKeyDecryptorBuilder(new BcPGPDigestCalculatorProvider()).build(INSTANCE._secretKeyPass.toCharArray());
        PGPSecretKey psKey = INSTANCE._secretKeyRingCollection.getSecretKey(pbe.getKeyID());
        if (psKey != null) {
            sKey = psKey.extractPrivateKey(decryptor);
        }
    }
    if (sKey == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unable to find secret key to decrypt the message");
    }

    InputStream clear = pbe.getDataStream(new BcPublicKeyDataDecryptorFactory(sKey));

    PGPObjectFactory plainFact = new PGPObjectFactory(clear);

    Object message;

    PGPOnePassSignatureList onePassSignatureList = null;
    PGPSignatureList signatureList = null;
    PGPCompressedData compressedData;

    message = plainFact.nextObject();
    ByteArrayOutputStream actualOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    while (message != null) {
        __l.trace(message.toString());
        if (message instanceof PGPCompressedData) {
            compressedData = (PGPCompressedData) message;
            plainFact = new PGPObjectFactory(compressedData.getDataStream());
            message = plainFact.nextObject();
        }

        if (message instanceof PGPLiteralData) {
            // have to read it and keep it somewhere.
            Streams.pipeAll(((PGPLiteralData) message).getInputStream(), actualOutput);
        } else if (message instanceof PGPOnePassSignatureList) {
            onePassSignatureList = (PGPOnePassSignatureList) message;
        } else if (message instanceof PGPSignatureList) {
            signatureList = (PGPSignatureList) message;
        } else {
            throw new PGPException("message unknown message type.");
        }
        message = plainFact.nextObject();
    }
    actualOutput.close();
    PGPPublicKey publicKey = null;
    byte[] output = actualOutput.toByteArray();
    if (onePassSignatureList == null || signatureList == null) {
        throw new PGPException("Poor PGP. Signatures not found.");
    } else {

        for (int i = 0; i < onePassSignatureList.size(); i++) {
            PGPOnePassSignature ops = onePassSignatureList.get(0);
            __l.trace("verifier : " + ops.getKeyID());
            PGPPublicKeyRingCollection pgpRing = new PGPPublicKeyRingCollection(
                    PGPUtil.getDecoderStream(publicKeyIn));
            publicKey = pgpRing.getPublicKey(ops.getKeyID());
            if (publicKey != null) {
                ops.init(new JcaPGPContentVerifierBuilderProvider().setProvider("BC"), publicKey);
                ops.update(output);
                PGPSignature signature = signatureList.get(i);
                if (ops.verify(signature)) {
                    Iterator<?> userIds = publicKey.getUserIDs();
                    while (userIds.hasNext()) {
                        String userId = (String) userIds.next();
                        __l.trace(String.format("Signed by {%s}", userId));
                    }
                    __l.trace("Signature verified");
                } else {
                    throw new SignatureException("Signature verification failed");
                }
            }
        }

    }

    if (pbe.isIntegrityProtected() && !pbe.verify()) {
        throw new PGPException("Data is integrity protected but integrity is lost.");
    } else if (publicKey == null) {
        throw new SignatureException("Signature not found");
    } else {
        fOut.write(output);
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Fun Fact: Porting this code to C# actually worked better than any of the actual C# examples for doing this.

Comment: You are adding else if the condition either signatureList will be null or onePassSignatureList will be null . How come this is working
because if code goes through this condition:
 else if (message instanceof PGPOnePassSignatureList) {
            onePassSignatureList = (PGPOnePassSignatureList) message;
        } 
the signatureList will be null and if this happens then come how 
PGPSignature signature = signatureList.get(i); doesn't give NPE

Answer (score 11):

Getting Bouncy Castle to play along is not always easy. Code-snipets from Stackoverflow make it *work just so*, but they are mostly arcane pieces of code that none of the users really understand.

The problem with this is: **In a production system *copy'n'paste snippets* quickly become "no go" and "do not touch" areas.**

Shelling out executables can have some serious  security implications, least of all is handling command line parameters (talking about filenames with spaces ... how do I know? Don't ask ...)

I had all of these (and more..) problems, and after some yak shaving I wrote a library to handle PGP with Bouncycastle.

Decrypting works like this:

```
final InputStream plaintextStream = BouncyGPG
               .decryptAndVerifyStream()
               .withConfig(keyringConfig)
               .andRequireSignatureFromAllKeys("sender@example.com")
               .fromEncryptedInputStream(cipherTextStream)
```

The library can be found at https://github.com/neuhalje/bouncy-gpg :

```
// in build.gradle add a dependency to bouncy castle and bouncy-gpg
//  ...
dependencies {
    compile 'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.56'
    compile 'org.bouncycastle:bcpg-jdk15on:1.56'
    //  ...
    compile 'name.neuhalfen.projects.crypto.bouncycastle.openpgp:bouncy-gpg:2.+'
```

Comment: Hi Jens, I am using your library and its really good. I am having this issue though where  I encrypted the file and signed with a user  test@test.com and then when i tried to decrypt using mac's Open PGP it says Verification failed for test@test.com even though the file is decrypted. Can you help plz

Comment: Please create an issue in the Github bugtracker and link it here (so that we can resolve the issue in the tracker and Update the answer here afterwards)

Comment: Having fought with Bouncy Castle for the past couple of days, I can verify this library is dope.

Comment: Hi, have you anything for PGP encryption ?

Comment: Yes, BouncyGPG supports encryption as well, just visit the Github repo https://github.com/neuhalje/bouncy-gpg

Answer (score 2):

You are calling:

```
encryptedDataGenerator.open(out, 4096)
```

where you probably meant:

```
encryptedDataGenerator.open(out, new byte[4096])
```

The first version is giving a size to open (which is wrong), the second version is giving a byte buffer.

(I know this is old, but came here because I had the same problem with some example code and so might others)