# How to verify file signature using Java and PGP public key?

Tags: java, pgp

I have a signed file. I need to verify the signature of a file against the PGP public key(txt file) using Java and Bounty castle.

Please assist i am completely new.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bouncycastle PGP decrypt and verify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19173181/bouncycastle-pgp-decrypt-and-verify)

Comment: I  tried bountycastle but I am unable to understand them. I have received file in (without extension) and public key as txt file. I am not understanding how to verify. If you could assist that would be really helpful.